# How can I simplify my matlab code? Can't find a way that works fine

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

Need help for simplifying my matlab code.

```
lambda = 1;
k = 2*pi/lambda;
w = 2*pi*v/lambda;
z=linspace(0,10,10000);
t=linspace(0,10,10);  %time
theta=(pi)*rand(1,length(t));   %random phase
for a=1:length(t)
    u1=1./(1+exp(-2.*(10e4).*(t(a)-z./v)));   %step function
    u2=1./(1+exp(-2.*(10e4).*(t(a)-z./v-1)));
    u3=1./(1+exp(-2.*(10e4).*(t(a)-z./v-2)));
    u4=1./(1+exp(-2.*(10e4).*(t(a)-z./v-3)));
    u5=1./(1+exp(-2.*(10e4).*(t(a)-z./v-4)));
    u6=1./(1+exp(-2.*(10e4).*(t(a)-z./v-5)));
    u7=1./(1+exp(-2.*(10e4).*(t(a)-z./v-6)));
    u8=1./(1+exp(-2.*(10e4).*(t(a)-z./v-7)));
    u9=1./(1+exp(-2.*(10e4).*(t(a)-z./v-8)));
    u10=1./(1+exp(-2.*(10e4).*(t(a)-z./v-9)));
    del_u1=u1-u2;
    del_u2=u2-u3;
    del_u3=u3-u4;
    del_u4=u4-u5;
    del_u5=u5-u6;
    del_u6=u6-u7;
    del_u7=u7-u8;
    del_u8=u8-u9;
    del_u9=u9-u10;
    y1=del_u1.*cos(k.*z-w.*t(a)+theta(1));
    y2=del_u2.*cos(k.*z-w.*t(a)+theta(2));
    y3=del_u3.*cos(k.*z-w.*t(a)+theta(3));
    y4=del_u4.*cos(k.*z-w.*t(a)+theta(4));
    y5=del_u5.*cos(k.*z-w.*t(a)+theta(5));
    y6=del_u6.*cos(k.*z-w.*t(a)+theta(6));
    y7=del_u7.*cos(k.*z-w.*t(a)+theta(7));
    y8=del_u8.*cos(k.*z-w.*t(a)+theta(8));
    y9=del_u9.*cos(k.*z-w.*t(a)+theta(9));
    y10=u10.*cos(k.*z-w.*t(a)+theta(10));
    yy=y1+y2+y3+y4+y5+y6+y7+y8+y9+y10;
    figure(1)
    plot(z,yy); grid on; axis image;
    drawnow;
end
```

The equation is not complicated but I got hard time trying to simplify it. I'm suppose to repeat the equation 1000 times, means
length(theta)=1000, u1~u1000, del_u1~del_u999, y1~y1000, yy=y1+y2+...y1000.
How can I simplify my code?

Comment: What is `v`? Is it a vector or a scalar?

Comment: @CrisLuengo `v` means the velocity of the wave. It’s a scalar. Equals to 1 in my original code.

Answer (score 3):

This is Matlab, aka Matrix Laboratory. *Write it in matrix form !*

instead of `u1` , `u2`, ... write the vector\array `u` ,  the `del_u` will become `u(1:end-1,:)-u(2:end,:)` etc.

same for if `y` is a vector\array  [`y1 y2 y3...`]... then `yy=sum(y)`.

This is very very basic matlab programing, you can read all about it in the documentation.

EDIT:

Here is an identical version of your code in the question (written and tested in Matlab 2019b), showing how to obtain the arrays and implement vectorization instead the inflation of variables `u1`,`u2`, and for loop etc.

```
u        = 1./(1+exp(-2.*(10e4).*  (t'-permute(0:9,[3 1 2])-z./v) ));
del_u    = cat(3,u(:,:,1:end-1)-u(:,:,2:end), u(:,:,end)); 
cos_term = cos(k.*z-w.*t'+permute(theta,[3 1 2]));
yy       = sum(del_u.*cos_term,3) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the advice.
I've tried using the vector/array already, I used function handle and cellfun.The problem when I'm using them is `u` and `y` have the `t` (time) in it, which I want to animate, but cellfun can only output scalar. Also the `theta` in `y` is random, it need to go with `y` and not changing while `t` is changing. That is the two main point why I comes back and tried it with the most stupid way. Any other function recommend?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you even need cellfun. I edited my answer to show you how your entire code collapse to simple vectorized and array based variables.

Comment: @bla, your answer is not correct. First, you need to delete one bracket from the end of the first row. Second, the `yy` that is computed from your code, is different from the `yy` that is computed from the original code (in the question). That because you don't iterate over `t` using one element from it each time, but you use all its elements at once. This also happened when you computed `cos_term`. The third problem is you wrote `del_u    =   [u(2:end,:)-u(1:end-1,:) ; u(end,:)];` instead of `del_u    =   [u(1:end-1,:)-u(2:end,:); u(end, :)];`.

Comment: if I wrote u1-u2 instead of u2-u1 is not really important here, but thanks for catching the inconsistency between the first part of my answer where I got it right, and the edit I added, where I reversed it by mistake...  the importance is to show case the vectorization aspect and making arrays instead of many variables...

Comment: lol.... nothing genius here :D happy that you find this valuable (permute is pretty useful for matrix operations going 3d and beyond)

Answer (score 1):

This code works well, without a need to change it when the size of the data is changed. This code also runs faster:

```
v = 1;
lambda = 1;
k = 2*pi/lambda;
w = 2*pi.*v./lambda;
z=linspace(0,10,10000);
t=linspace(0,10,10);  %time
theta=(pi)*rand(1,length(t));   %random phase
for a=1:length(t)
   u = 1./(1+exp(-2.*(10e4).*(bsxfun(@minus, t(a) - z./v, [0:9]'))));
   del_u = [u(1:end-1, :)-u(2:end, :); u(end, :)];
   y = del_u.*cos(bsxfun(@plus, k.*z - w.*t(a), theta'));
   yy = sum(y);
   figure(1)
   plot(z,yy); grid on; axis image;
   drawnow;
end
```

Comment: `v=1` ,I forgot to define it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I did not be sure it works well on all versions, so I did not take the risk... Thanks for this information, the code is really simpler without using `bsxfun`. I edited my answer, but where it does not work on all versions without `bsxfun` I left it.